# Change properties of Columns and Searchresults in Sharepoint Library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, json, modern-document-library, column-settings

I´m wondering if there is any way that you can change properties on columns when using search in sharepoint library? When you use search this library and then press more you will land on a new searchresult page with columns from your library. I want to be able to set json code on one of those columns. Is there any way that this is possible?

As I have understand the search result page is only a type of filter from your original librarypage?

For instans I want to have my JSon previewcode enabled and also want to change properties on the columns. heck out the pictures to see what I mean.

The 3:rd picture shows how it looks in the Document library, i also want to be able to have the same view in the search resultview.

Can anyone help?

THX in advance[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Applying JSON formatting on the search result page is possible. You can find the entrance by clicking on **View options** on the menu. Available columns differ in each document library.

Changing properties of columns do not seem be an option. Only **filtering** or **grouping** on columns are supported on the search result page.

[image]